Why reverse the KEY and IV before loading into the state in Trivium cipher?
I am reading the this repo, a python implementation of Trivium cipher.
They convert the KEY and IV hexes to bits using hex_to_bits function:
# Convert strings of hex to strings of bytes and back, little-endian style
_allbytes = dict([("%02X" % i, i) for i in range(256)])


def hex_to_bytes(s):
    return [_allbytes[s[i : i + 2].upper()] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]


def hex_to_bits(s):
    return [(b >> i) & 1 for b in hex_to_bytes(s) for i in range(8)]


Them they reverse the KEY and IV before loading them into the Trivium state:
 // reverse with [::-1]
 KEY = hex_to_bits("0F62B5085BAE0154A7FA")[::-1]
 IV = hex_to_bits("288FF65DC42B92F960C7")[::-1]

 # Encoding a string
 trivium_encoder = Trivium(KEY, IV)

Why would they do this? I don’t see this mentioned anywhere in the Trivium specifications.
I've test it with several test vectors from here, and it produce correct results.

The reversal is likely required because of the difference in endianness. The title of the repo reads "Trivium (Little Endian)". So if the cipher is defined using numbers or a specific byte order then it may be required to reverse them.
I don't see anything specific to endianness in the specs, but what I expect is that the original SW implementation reads from memory into registers reversing the bytes at that time, and then performs the ops such as shifting. Of course in that case you'd need to do the same thing in Python.
Note that python / humans generally have the most significant byte to the left when specifying numbers, i.e. big endian. Most CPU's are however little endian. "Left" here is the lowest index and "right" the highest byte index.

"reversing the bytes"—that clears up my confusion. Thank you!
